# Implementing request-response with Rx.NET

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

The code below simulates an HTTP-like protocol over a WebSocket connection. Each request expects a corresponding response. If a response is not received within a specified timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out.

I'm not that good at Rx.NET, which is why I open the topic.

The code works but I have several concerns.

1. `InvokeAsync` should be executed in a separate thread, and that's for sure. However, `Observable.Return(serverMsg).ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)` seems to be leaky, mostly because we don't wait for the observable to execute, so that we can dispose it afterwards.
2. Is `Observable.Timer` the most suitable mechanism for implementing a request timeout if no response is received within a certain time frame?

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

var manager = new PendingRequestManager();

// Simulate adding a pending request.
manager.TryAdd("Request1", 
    onSuccess: content => { Console.WriteLine($"Success: {content}"); return ValueTask.CompletedTask; }, 
    onError: error => { Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}"); return ValueTask.CompletedTask; }, 
    requestTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
    matcher: msg => msg.Content == "Response1");

// Simulate the server sending a message that matches a pending request.
await manager.TryInvokeAsync(new ServerMsg { Content = "Response1" });

Console.ReadLine();

public class ServerMsg
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PendingRequestInfo
{
    private readonly Func<string, ValueTask> _onSuccess;
    private readonly Func<ServerMsg, bool> _matcher;

    public PendingRequestInfo(
        Func<string, ValueTask> onSuccess,
        Func<string, ValueTask> onError,
        Func<ServerMsg, bool> matcher,
        IDisposable timerDisposable)
    {
        _onSuccess = onSuccess;
        OnError = onError;
        _matcher = matcher;
        TimerDisposable = timerDisposable;
    }

    public Func<string, ValueTask> OnError { get; }
    public IDisposable TimerDisposable { get; }

    public bool Matches(ServerMsg msg) => _matcher(msg);

    public ValueTask InvokeAsync(ServerMsg serverMsg)
    {
        Observable.Return(serverMsg)
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await _onSuccess(item.Content);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await OnError($"An error occurred while processing the server message: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }))
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe();

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class PendingRequestManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, PendingRequestInfo> _pendingRequests = new();

    public bool TryAdd(object request, Func<string, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError, TimeSpan requestTimeout, Func<ServerMsg, bool> matcher)
    {
        if (_pendingRequests.ContainsKey(request))
        {
            // Duplicate; skip.
            return false;
        }

        var timerDisposable = Observable.Timer(requestTimeout)
            .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
            {
                if (_pendingRequests.TryRemove(request, out var pendingRequestInfo))
                {
                    await pendingRequestInfo.OnError("Request timed out");
                    pendingRequestInfo.TimerDisposable.Dispose();
                }
            }))
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe();
        
        _pendingRequests[request] = new PendingRequestInfo(onSuccess, onError, matcher, timerDisposable);
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> TryInvokeAsync(ServerMsg serverMsg)
    {
        var request = _pendingRequests.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => _pendingRequests[key].Matches(serverMsg));
        if (request == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Dispose timer immediately to prevent it from firing while processing the message.
        _pendingRequests[request].TimerDisposable.Dispose();

        try
        {
            await _pendingRequests[request].InvokeAsync(serverMsg);
        }
        finally
        {
            _pendingRequests.TryRemove(request, out _);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```